# Stored procedure to insert values in a table where JOINS are involved

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, stored-procedures

This is the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mysp_AddOrderLine
    (@pOrderId INT,
     @pQuantity INT,
     @pRestaurantId INT,
     @pFoodId INT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO SALES.OrderLine (OrderId, Quantity, RestaurantId, FoodId, LineTotal)
        SELECT 
            @pOrderId, @pQuantity, @pRestaurantId, @pFoodId, 
            SUM(SOL.Quantity * F.UnitPrice) 
        FROM 
            SALES.OrderLine SOL 
        INNER JOIN 
            RESTAURANT.Food F ON SOL.FoodId = F.FoodId
        -- Do you also need to filter on @pRestaurantId
        WHERE 
            SOL.OrderId = @pOrderId AND SOL.FoodId = @pFoodId;

    RETURN 0
END

DECLARE @pOrderId INT = 515, @pQuantity INT = 2, 
        @pRestaurantId INT = 6, @pFoodId INT = 24;

EXEC mysp_AddOrderLine @pOrderId, @pQuantity, @pRestaurantId, @pFoodId;
```

`OrderLine` table has no values at present, so I am inserting new values there.
It has attributes like `OrderLineId` which is an identity, `OrderId` which is returned from `Order` table, `Quantity` we have to insert that via stored procedure, `RestaurantId` which is returned from `Restaurant` table and `FoodId` which is from `Food` table.

Please see the attached screenshot. Why is `LineTotal` null in the `OrderLine` table? It is supposed to be 12 * 2 = 24?

[SampleImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTY2q.jpg)

Comment: I don't understand your question, the value should be whatever you need it to be for your SP to return the result set you want.

Comment: don't think parameter pLineTotal should be part of your stored procedure. It is NOT a parameter you are passing into the SP. It seems to be calculated internally. Your create procedure should NOT have this >>, @pLineTotal money . Just declare and set it with the formula internally to the SP.

Comment: This worked and I also modified logic SELECT @pLineTotal = (SOL.Quantity*F.UnitPrice). However, the results are not correct.         
OrderLineId OrderId Qty RestaurantId FoodId LineTotal                       
   39               515   2        6         24 NULL
   40               516   3        2         30 24.00
   41               517   5        8         32 48.00 Getting the result of LineTotal as NULL for first column and first row LineTotal result is stored in second row LineTotal result and the result of second row LineTotal is stored in third row. Not sure what happened.

Comment: @Neha you're missing a `where` clause, see my answer below.

Comment: @Neha another question, but do you really want to add *another* `OrderLine` to the order just to contain the `sum`? Or do you actually want to update the existing `orderline` with the `linetotal`?

Comment: @DaleK There exists no values for LineTotal in the OrderLine Table, I have just created a coulmn by that name. I have to insert new values to the created column "LineTotal" via SP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for the `@pLineTotal` variable to exist at all, do the calculation and insert in one go as below. Note also the following points:

1. Don't prefix your SP with `sp` its too close to `sp_` which is a special system prefix.
2. You can define and set multiple variables in one go which is a lot neater and easier to read IMO.
3. I have guessed at this, but I think you are missing a `where` clause if you want to sum your order items for a given order.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE mysp_AddOrderLine
    (
      @pOrderId int
      , @pQuantity int
      , @pRestaurantId int
      , @pFoodId int
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      INSERT INTO SALES.OrderLine(OrderId, Quantity, RestaurantId, FoodId, LineTotal)
        SELECT @pOrderId, @pQuantity, @pRestaurantId, @pFoodId, SUM(SOL.Quantity*F.UnitPrice) 
        FROM SALES.OrderLine SOL 
        INNER JOIN RESTAURANT.Food F ON SOL.FoodId = F.FoodId
        -- Do you also need to filter on @pRestaurantId
        WHERE SOL.OrderId = @pOrderId and SOL.FoodId = @pFoodId;

      RETURN 0;
    END

    DECLARE @pOrderId INT = 516, @pQuantity INT = 2, @pRestaurantId INT = 6, @pFoodId INT = 24;

    EXEC mysp_AddOrderLine @pOrderId, @pQuantity, @pRestaurantId, @pFoodId;
```

In order to test this I need some sample data in the form:

```
declare @Food table (FoodId int, UnitPrice money)

insert into @Food (FoodId, UnitPrice)
  values (2,12), (32,2), (30,16), (22,10)

declare @OrderLine table (FoodId int, OrderLineId int, OrderId int, Quantity int)

insert into @OrderLine (FoodId, OrderLineId, OrderId, Quantity)
 values (2,1,1,2), (32,1,1,5), (30,1,1,7), (22,1,1,2)

declare @pOrderId int = 1
  , @pQuantity int
  , @pRestaurantId int
  , @pFoodId int = 2

select * from @Food
select * from @OrderLine

SELECT @pOrderId, @pQuantity, @pRestaurantId, @pFoodId
  , SUM(SOL.Quantity*F.UnitPrice)
  --, SOL.Quantity, F.UnitPrice 
FROM @OrderLine SOL 
INNER JOIN @Food F ON SOL.FoodId = F.FoodId
where SOL.OrderId = @pOrderId and SOL.FoodId = @pFoodId;
```

NOTE: If you are actually trying to add a new OrderLine maybe you actually want this which adds a new record and computes the line total:

```
INSERT INTO SALES.OrderLine(OrderId, Quantity, RestaurantId, FoodId, LineTotal)
  SELECT @pOrderId, @pQuantity, @pRestaurantId, @pFoodId, @pQuantity*F.UnitPrice) 
  FROM RESTAURANT.Food F
  WHERE F.FoodId = @pFoodId;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The above code is returning LineTotal as NULL for all the rows. If I make some small change in the logic like  LineTotal = SOL.Quantity*F.UnitPrice, the above code is not returning any values I just see everything blank with only column names, none of the rows are affected.

Comment: @Neha You need to provide some sample data and expected results then so I can test it.

Comment: I have given four sample inputs :(FoodId,UnitPrice) --(24,12) (32,2) (30,16) (22,10)  it is there in Food TABLE and OrderLine Table should have LineTotal automatically inserted .There are other attributes in OrderLine TABLE like OrderLineId which is identity, OrderId, Quantity which is (2,5,7,2), RestaurantId and FoodId (24,32,30,22) which is from Food TABLE. Finally my LineTotal should be (12*2),(2*5),(16*7),(10*2) respectively for first 4 rows. However, I am getting NULL for first four rows and again if I INSERT the same values using SP its correct. 1st insert for anything is always NULL.

Comment: Please [edit] them directly into the question and format them - its impossible to read data from a comment,

Comment: @Neha also why are you passing a quantity in, `@pQuantity`,  when you already have a quantity

Comment: @Neha I've added some test data and test query, please copy that out, get it working with actual test data and paste it into your question.

Comment: Don't you need a `GROUP BY` in there?

Comment: @Alex - I wish I knew :) expected behaviour and results is a bit lacking. I suspect not, because I suspect the parameters specify a particular order which needs to be summed.

Comment: @DaleK I do not have quantity, I have to insert it via SP. Please see my edited version again. I have posted an image.

Comment: @Neha see my last edit, the last SQL I added to my answer as I think it answers your question. Of course you are going to get null if you query the OrderLine table and its empty.